# Placeholder colors is different in IE and FF

Tags: css, placeholder

I have HTML form and placeholder css code

```
#email::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight:400;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#333 !important;
}
#email::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight:400;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#333 !important;
}
#email:-ms-input-placeholder { font-weight:400;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#333 !important;
}
#email::-ms-input-placeholder { font-weight:400;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#333 !important;
}
#email::placeholder { font-weight:400;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#333 !important;
}
```

#### IE example:

[image]

#### FF example:

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: Seems like this pseudo is a working draft..it is not fully supported yet...check the supported browser list in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. The syntax only supported for IE 10 and above. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772745(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hey,  @WEBSITEFREELANCE, did my answer solved your issue?

Comment: `(1)` it doesn't matter. obviously things differ between browser `(2)` what you are really asking is how to change input placeholder  via css, which has many answers already (you should have searched) `(3)` it's unclear what your are asking since you simply said "help" without explaining what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox the color of the placeholder looks faded when compared to other browsers. In the image below, Firefox is shown on the left whilst Chrome is shown on the right:

[image]

This is because, by default, all placeholders in Firefox have an opacity value applied to them, so in order to fix this you need to simply reset that value, in your case add:

```
#email::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I learned this from CSS-tricks, [here's the source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/#firefox-placeholder-color).